# Receive form input data with PHP POST

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using the jQuery tag-it plugin, which basically has an input field. Everything works well, but I am unable to receive the input field value by submitting the form with PHP.

Here's the form part:

```
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post">        
        <div class="line">
            <label for="tags">Tags</label>
            <ul id="mytags"></ul>
        </div>      
       <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is PHP part:

```
<?
    if ($_POST[submit]) {

    $tags = $_POST[mytags];
    echo $tags;

    }

    ?>
```

The demo of the plugin is here: http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html
and the javascript code is here: http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/js/tag-it.js
I'll be thankful for any help.

Comment: lol do u have any other helpful code?

Comment: @Neal, I posted the direct link of javascript code of the plugin.

Comment: yes. of the plugin, but not of what you, yourself did.

Comment: @Neal, I just want to receive the tag input by submitting the form by the code i wrote above but it does not receive the posted data.

Comment: ther is no posted data, you ddnt use input fields

Comment: @bensiu, the plugin displays input field with javascript. The link of the javascript part of plugin is posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acutal tags are stored in this form field which is created for each tag:

```
function create_choice (value) {    
  // some stuff
  el += "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"display:none;\" value=\""+value+"\" name=\"item[tags][]\">\n";
  // some other stuff
}
```

So you must look out not for 'mytags' but for **$_POST['item']['tags']** in your PHP Code which will then give you an array of the tags.

Comment: if i read it right then he has to look for $_REQUEST['item']['tags'] as opposed to $_REQUEST['tags'] as you advised

Comment: Should it be like `$tags = $_POST['tags'];` ? because even this doesnt get the value.

Comment: it should be like $tags = $_POST['item']['tags']

Answer (score 4):

in tpl

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tags-input").tagit({
        fieldName: "tag[]",
        availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"]
    });
});
</script>
```

use fieldName: "tag[]" attribute, in backend print_r($_POST) and check what it will display

Comment: `fieldname: "tag[]` 
does the job. The response from print_r($_POST) will be:

`array(1) { ["tags"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "tag1" [1]=> string(4) "tag2" [2]=> string(4) "tag3" } }`

Comment: nailed it. this was they key to add, without it, i wasn't getting anything: >>> fieldName: "tag[]", 

thanks man! :)

Answer (score 1):

`ul` is not a form element which would be submitted, it's a UI element. And you need to use quotes around your array indexes, like this:
`if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Answer (score 1):

the code should look like this:

```
<?
if ($_POST['submit']) {

$tags = $_POST['mytags'];
echo $tags;

}

?>
```

you forgot the enclosing `'`

if you forget that php treats the submit in `$_POST[submit]` as a constant

EDIT:

try this:

```
<?
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be **NO** posted data

your code does not use any input fields!

Comment: Looking at the plugin, it creates a bunch of hidden inputs on the fly. OP has only posted the starting HTML

Comment: @JohnP , yes, but that plugin also does not use a submit button

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your plugin, it seems to create hidden input fields on the fly as you add tags.

Assuming that part of the code is actually working, put the following into your PHP code.

```
<?php 
    var_dump($_POST); //this has to be in the page you POST to
?>
```

See if all your tags are showing up. If it is, then your JS works and your PHP is at fault. **As user @ITroubs mentions, you should quote your array indices**. See if that fixes it.

If no data is displayed, then your JS plugin is not working properly.

Using firebug, add a couple of tags and inspect inside the LI element of your list and see if any hidden INPUTS are being created.

Also check if there are any JS errors being reported.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and solved:

```
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post">        
        <div class="line">
            <label for="tags">Tags</label>
            <ul id="mytags" name="item[tags][]"></ul>
        </div>      
       <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is PHP part:

```
    <?
        if ($_POST[submit]) {

    $tags = $_POST["item"]["tags"];
foreach($tags as $i=>$v)
{
     $tagsf .= $v;
     if($i < (count($tags)-1))
    $tagsf .= ",";
}

echo $tagsf;
//This shows the tags with ",". Example: dog,cat,bird,onion

        }

    ?>
```